# How do I filter data from a CSV file in Excel or with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, excel, csv, filtering, spreadsheet

I have a huge CSV file (over 57,000 rows and 50 columns) that I need to analyze.

Edit: Hi guys, thanks for your answers and comments, but I am still really confused about how to do this in Ruby, and I have no idea how to use MySQL. I will try to be more specific:

The CSV files:

[CSV on Storm Data Details for 2015](https://application.adadevelopersacademy.org/assets/2015_c20160810.csv-da99899293733c7536ba143cbe776239.gz)

[CSV on Storm Data Details for 2000](https://application.adadevelopersacademy.org/assets/2000_c20160223.csv-efe96cf76f088697cd76b0820093f8c6.gz)

The questions:
Prior to question start, for all answers, exclude all rows that have a County/Parish, Zone, or Marine name that begins with the letters A, B, or C.

1. Find the month in 2015 where the State of Washington had the largest number of storm events. How many days of storm-free weather occurred in that month?
2. How many storms impacting trees happened between 8PM EST and 8AM EST in 2000?
3. In which year (2000 or 2015) did storms have a higher monetary impact within the boundaries of the 13 original colonies?

The problems:

1) I was able to use filters in Excel to determine that the most "Thunderstorm Wind" events in Washington happened in July (6 entries), and there were 27 days of storm-free weather. However, when I tried to check my work in Spotfire, I got completely different results. (7 entries in May, and 28 days of storm-free weather in May. Excel only found two Thunderstorm Wind events in May.) Do you know what could be causing this discrepancy?

2) There are two columns where damage to trees might be mentioned: Event_Narrative and Episode_Narrative. Would it be possible to search both columns for "tree" and filter the spreadsheet down to only those results? Multiple-column filtering is apparently impossible in Excel. I would also need to find a way to omit the word "street" in the results (because it contains the word "tree").

The method I came up with for the time range is to filter to only EST and AST results, then filter Begin_Time to 2000 to 2359 and 0 to 759 and repeat those ranges to filter End_Time. This appears to work.

3) I was able to filter the states to Delaware, Pennsylvania, New Jersey, Georgia, Connecticut, Massachusetts, Maryland, South Carolina, New Hampshire, Virginia, New York, North Carolina, and Rhode Island. It seems like a simple task to add all the values in Columns Y and Z (Damage_Property, Damage_Crops) and compare between the two years, but the values are written in the form "32.79K" and I cannot figure out how to make the adding equation work in that format or convert the values into integers.

Also, the question is asking for the original territory of the colonies, which is not the same as the territory those states now occupy. Do you know of a way to resolve this issue? Even if I had the time to look up each city listed, there does not seem to be a database of cities in the original 13 colonies online, and even if there was, the names of the cities may now be different.

---

I am learning Ruby and some people have suggested that I try to use the Ruby CSV library to put the data into an array. I have looked at some tutorials that sort of describe how to do that, but I still don't understand how I would filter the data down to only what I need.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you consider loading the data into a database? Feels like SQL might be a better choice than Ruby and a big array.

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Comment: Why can you only filter on one thing in Excel? Do you have some limited version of Excel?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the data so I could play with it. You can get the record count pretty easily in Ruby. I just did it in irb:

```
require 'csv'

details = []
CSV.foreach("StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d2015_c20160818.csv") do |row|
  details << row
end

results = details.select do |field|
  [field[-2], field[-3]].any? { |el| el[/\btree\b/i] } && field[8] == "CALIFORNIA"
end

results.count
 => 125
```

I just used array indices. You could zip things together and make hashes for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post this as a comment but I don't have enough rep. Anyways:

I have converted CSV/xls files to JSON in the past with the help of some nodejs packages and uploaded them to my couchbase database. Within couchbase I can query with N1ql (really just SQL) which will allow you to achieve your goal of filtering multiple criterias. Like spickermann said, a database will solve your problem.

Edit:
My-Sql also supports importing a CSV file to a My-SQL table. Will be easier than the CSV to JSON to Couchbase

Csv-to-json 
https://github.com/cparker15/csv-to-json/blob/master/README.md